# fscanf is somehow changing a node (in c)

Tags: c, trie, scanf

I am new to c and have been stuck on this bug for hours.  My code reads each word from  a txt file and then stores the word in a node in a trie.

I have narrowed the problem down to the area marked off by asterisks:
at that point I have successfully added the first word to the trie and check that the correct node's value matched the word. Then, I use `fscanf` to save the next word in the file as the char 'add'.  Then, printing out the exact same thing as before, the node's word should have remained the same. However, it has somehow been changed to the new word that was just read from the file.

How is this even possible??

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

trie_t* trie = malloc(sizeof(trie_t));
trie_init(trie);

int ret;
char* add = malloc(128);
FILE* file = fopen(argv[5], "r");
if (file == NULL) {
    /* Failed to open the file for reading */
    return 0;
}

while (1) {*********************
    if (trie->head->children != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", trie->head->children->word);
    }
    ret = fscanf(file, "%s", add);
    //printf("word = %s\n",toAdd);
    if (trie->head->children != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", trie->head->children->word);
    }****************************
    if (ret == EOF) {
        /* End of file */
        ret = 1;
        break;
    } else if (ret <= 0) {
        printf("fails");
        /* Failed to read a word from the file */
        break;
    } else {
        printf("gets here\n");
        /* Succesfully read a word */
        int x = trie_add(trie, add);
        printf("%d\n",x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only assigning memory once for `add` at:

```
char* add = malloc(128);
```

You need to assign memory for each word, that is, you need to move the `malloc` to your read cycle.

What the code is doing as you posted it is: allocate 128 bytes once, and then overwrite that memory space once and again every time you `scanf()`.

Also, at `char* add = malloc(128);` you should assign it as `char* add = malloc(128 * sizeof(char));` just to be clear and portable :)

Comment: While I am on the forefront of recommending use of `sizeof` in `malloc()` calls, please note that `sizeof (char)` is 1. Always. On all platforms. So it really doesn't do that very much to improve things, here. You can make it type-independent for clarity by using `char *add = malloc(128 * sizeof *add);`, that would be my preferred form.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are storing the pointer `add` in `trie_t` in `trie_add` function. In this case, since you are reusing the same memory location `add` for reading the next string, the content of the pointer pointed by `add` changes. Since you are just storing this pointer in `trie` the content of that node also changes because of this. To solve this, you need to allocate memory again using `malloc` just before the new string is read from file using `fscanf`.